# Module of a Complex Number

Tags: complex-numbers

i need to prove the following statement:

for $w \in \Bbb{C}$ , $|w|=\max\{\Re(wz), z \in \Bbb{C}, |z|<1 \}$, where $\Bbb{C}$ denotes the complex numbers.

I was trying to write down conditions on the real and imaginary part of $w$ and $z$ so that at the end only the max over only the real part of the product matter. But i could not find a convincing solution.

I appreciate any comment.

Answer (score 0):

Call $\omega = r e^{i\theta}$ and $z = \rho e^{i\phi}$ with the constraint $\rho \le 1 $, then

$$
\Re(z\omega) = \Re(r\rho e^{i(\theta + \phi)}) = r\rho \Re(e^{i(\theta + \phi)}) = r\rho \cos(\theta + \phi)
$$

Since $-1\le \cos t \le 1$, then the maximum value is +1 and so is the maximum value of $\rho$, therefore

$$
\max \{\Re(\omega z): |z| < 1 \} = \max\{r\rho \cos(\theta + \phi): r\le 1, \phi \in \Bbb{R} \} = \max\{r\rho, |\rho|\le 1\} = r = |\omega|
$$

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false as the example $w=1$ shows: indeed, if $|z|<1$, we have $\Re(wz)=\Re(z)<1$, so the set doesn't reach a maximum.

The statement becomes true if $\max$ is changed into $\sup$ or $|z|<1$ is changed into $|z|\le1$.

On the other hand, the condition $|z|\le 1$ can be simplified into $|z|=1$.

Let's prove $|w|=\sup\{\Re(wz):|z|<1\}$

This is obvious for $w=0$, so we assume $w\ne0$. First, write $w=ru$, with $r>0$ and $|u|=1$. Then the statement boils down to showing that
$$
\sup\{\Re(uz):|z|<1\}=1
$$
Note that $\Re(uz)\le|uz|=|u|\,|z|=|z|<1$; on the other hand if we take $z=su^{-1}$, with $0<s<1$, $\Re(uz)=\Re(s)=s$ and $\sup\{s:0<s<1\}=1$.

Let's prove that $|w|=\sup\{\Re(wz):|z|=1\}$. Again, we can assume $w\ne0$ and write $w=ru$ as before. Thus we only need to prove that
$$
\max\{\Re(uz):|z|=1\}=1
$$
which follows from the fact that $\Re(uz)\le|uz|=1$ and that, for $z=u^{-1}$, $\Re(uz)=1$.